# Can a Participe Présent be used in place of "parce que" to explain a reason?

Tags: grammaire

> Je viens d'acheter un domaine. Son ancien propriétaire **souhaitant** s'en débarrasser rapidement.

I’m quite sure that the second sentence explains a reason for the first. A Participe Présent (like the "souhaitant" in this context) can be used in place of "parce que"?

> {=?} Je viens d'acheter un domaine. **Parce que** son ancien propriétaire **souhaitait** s'en débarrasser rapidement.

Comment: You can use it, but I wouldn't put it into another sentence => `Je viens d'acheter un domaine*,* son ancien propriétaire souhaitant s'en débarrasser rapidement.`

Comment: You can remove "souhaitant" from the title of your question -- the participe présent of pretty much any verb can be used to introduce a causal clause as an alternative to parce que + indicatif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bonjour,

you are right, both are correct. The first version ("souhaitant") being more literate.

Please note that to be grammatically correct, both versions would need a comma between your two sentences:

> Je viens d'acheter un domaine, son ancien propriétaire souhaitant s'en débarrasser rapidement.
>
> Je viens d'acheter un domaine, parce que son ancien propriétaire souhaitait s'en débarrasser rapidement.

or

> Je viens d'acheter un domaine. Son ancien propriétaire souhaitait s'en débarrasser rapidement.

Comment: The comma before "parce que" in the second sentence is not necessary and strikes me as unusual. I would write : "Je viens d'acheter un domaine parce que son ancien propriétaire souhaitait s'en débarrasser rapidement.". I found conflicting sources on this topic : "Les compléments de phrase placés après le groupe du verbe ne sont normalement pas détachés par une virgule, à moins de vouloir créer un effet d'insistance" [for alloprof](http://goo.gl/bwhdxG), but [the Canadian translation bureau](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect6&info0=6.1) is less specific.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both examples mean the same.

The first and the second example you have given are both right.

However, I think that there is a little difference between each one.

The second case is generally used to explain (Parce que) what you did in the first sentence. For example you would say : J'ai acheté une maison parce que je voulais être propriétaire. It is the direct reason why you bought an house, you wouldn't buy an house because someone want to sell it but you buy an house because you want to buy one.

Don't hesitate to comment if you need more explanations.